# Why is this happening with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am working on a c++ project and I am using cmake as the build system, so my workflow here is make changes to code. then,

```
rm -r build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make
```

Now I added glew as a dependency to the project, so whenever I try to run `make` I get an error saying `SDL.h not found(this was working before)`.After sometime I decided to check `CMakeCache.txt`.opened it using `vim` then `:wq` that's all I did now if I run `make`, my project is building successfully, I am not sure why this is happening, Can anyone tell me why?

**ps: added gif of this event, check it out to get a clear picture**

**(the code i am working on is linked as well, this exact issue is in this commit "dd4452b45c733e0612bc5f3c632e9d1a08be8072")**

[link to gif](http://showterm.io/f757552299b3e68b10a8f)

[link to code](https://github.com/bindingofisaac/gamelib)

Comment: the `build` directory should generally not be in the same directory as CMakeLists.txt. Also why are you deleting the build directory everytime?

Comment: ok, so i created the build directory in a different location still the same results. As for "why am i deleting the build directory everytime.." (i really don't know, it just makes me safe and happy :) ) @WorldSEnder

Comment: The build directory contains cached compiled object files, you force the compiler to regenerate them every run, even when you didn't change anything in some of them, which will hit you hard when you have bigger projects.

Comment: ok i will stop, deleting the build directory. Anyway right now i am deleting the directory because i am changing my CMakeLists.txt file as well.

Comment: @WorldSEnder _"you force the compiler to regenerate"_ - a complete rebuild may be desirable, especially if you are working on the CMake-files as is the case for the OP's problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variables in cmake are limited to the scope of the directory they are in plus their subdirectories.

This, calling find_module() in the gamelib subdirectory does not find that module for use in the main directory.

The preferred way to propagate include directory dependencies is to add them to the target (in the gamelib directory), like this:

```
target_include_directories(gamelib BEFORE PRIVATE
$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR}>
$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR}>
)

target_include_directories(gamelib SYSTEM BEFORE PUBLIC
$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR}>
$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR}>
)
```

then you don't need to even mention them in any executable that uses gamelib.

Comment: you are saying that calling find_module() in gamelib subdirectory does not add them to main directory, that is fine because i am building gamelib subdirectory into a static library, and then linking it with the main directories target, but the problem is with include directories, and the syntax you gave for propagating include dirs from top level to sub directories is not clear to me currently, i will read and try to put it in my code and let you know if its working :) .

Comment: @bindingofisaac the documentation in cmake on this subject (and many others) is not immediately clear, but once you understand the concept it will change your life (for the better!!). The basic idea is that each target carries all its dependency information with it, in different forms whether it is being referenced by another project in the build tree or whether it is being used as an installed library (see the export command). Happy reading :)

Comment: thanks man this works perfectly, now i am trying to understand 
[documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html)

Comment: @bindingofisaac yes, good luck with that. It took me months to figure it out :)